# How can I list only available security updates?

Tags: apt, security

I am aware of the command

```
/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable
```

which gives output like

```
7 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.
```

but how can I list only the security patches I need to install on my current Ubuntu?

On CentOS we can use

```
yum check-update --security
```

Is there an equivalent command in APT?

Comment: This question is not duplicate!!
In Ubuntu, I need detailing of which security packages will being get updated along with there version.
I only want the system should be up to date with the Security packages!!